# Data value doubled without reason SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, `tbl_income` and `order_total`.

[image]

Then I call the data with this query:

```
select SUM(total_price) as total_daily, date 
from order_total 
group by date having year(date)=2020

select sum(income) as daily_income, date 
from tbl_income 
group by date
```

[image]

Then I want the sum of that 2 sum table, I call them with this query

```
select sum(coalesce(total_price ,0))+sum(coalesce(income,0)) as income,order_total.date as date 
from order_total  
left join tbl_income on order_total.date=tbl_income.date 
left join Spending_Table on order_total.date=Spending_Table.date  
group by order_total.date 
having  year(order_total.date)=2020
```

[image]

As you can see the 5th data (2020-04-30) is doubled, that should be 685000. I tried to delete the row and input it again but still having the same issue, the 5th income data always doubled. What makes it strange the first data still works normally. How to fix this?

Comment: If the answer doesn't help can you add context around the Spending Table?  You are joining on the Spending table by date.  What is in that table, why are you including it in the join? I Started this for testing https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da8940e51c46e9120462abff8149ee50

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate *before* joining:

```
select coalesce(o.date, i.date) as date, o.total_daily, i.daily_income
from (select SUM(total_price) as total_daily, date 
      from order_total 
      where year(date) = 2020
      group by date
     ) o full join 
     (select sum(income) as daily_income, date 
      from tbl_income 
      group by date
     ) i
     on o.date = i.date;
```